# Autofac ContainerBuilder.Populate() will not accept a ServiceCollection

Tags: dependency-injection, autofac

I'm trying to do the following so that I can add HttpClient configs to a service collection. This is a .NET 4.8 Windows Service Application. I get the error shown in the image.  How might I accomplish this?

```
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<MyService>();
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            builder.Populate(new ServiceCollection().AddHttpClient("TheApiClient", client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://catfact.ninja");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            }));
            var container = builder.Build();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `AddHttpClient` method an `IHttpClientBuilder` object and you're trying to pass that to the `Populate` method, instead of passing the `ServiceCollection`. Change your code to the following:

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<MyService>();
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddHttpClient("TheApiClient", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://catfact.ninja");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
})
builder.Populate(services);
var container = builder.Build();
```